# Unable to connect properly to an open port on my Windows VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, windows-server

So I have this setup, I have a Windows Server 2019 with a RASA open source server installed.
RASA works on Port 5005 so I added an inbound port for 5005.

So on my computer I tried accessing use < Public IP > :5005 and it didn't work even though if I use use < Private IP > :5005 or localhost:5005 in the virtual machine it works fine.

I also tried accessing the use < Public IP > :5005 inside the virtual machine and it didn't work.
The error is took to long to respond

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could add a rule to the Windows firewall inside the Server to expose the port for the public and private profiles. You could open a command prompt as an administrator on Azure VM and run the following command.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=RASA dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5005
```

Comment: Ugh, I was expecting adding an inbound port would automatically add a firewall rule in VM. They should put that on the instruction when opening a port since it only shows the Azure side